Is this derivation of the WKB approximation ruined by both principal and non-principal roots of $-i$ appearing in different steps?
In the first screenshot of pg 203 of my textbook below, discussing the turning point conditions in the WKB approximation in quantum mechanics, you can see they state
$i(-i)^{1/3} = -1$
which implies that they define $-i = exp(i3π/2)$, which is not the principal root.
Then in the second screenshot of pg 204, they invoke (without proof anywhere in the book) the large argument form of the Bessel functions of the first kind.
To properly understand the large argument form, I used pg 10-12 of these notes: https://young.physics.ucsc.edu/250/bessel.pdf
This proof uses the principal root $-i = exp(-iπ/2)$, and in the course of the proof it ends up getting raised to the power of $-(v+1)$ where $v$ is an arbitrary real number. So the choice of $arg(-i)$ will matter here. Using $-i = exp(i3π/2)$ in this derivation would not work because adding the results of the steepest descent approximations to the two contours in figure 4 would no longer satisfy Euler's formula.
So, this WKB discussion explicitly takes a cube root of $-i = exp(i3π/2)$, but relies on the proof of the large argument form of the Bessel functions, which takes nth roots of  $-i = exp(-iπ/2)$. The argument in the textbook cannot be modified by redefining the constants $a$ and $b$, while instead using $-i = exp(-iπ/2)$, because of how they want to apply the trig addition theorem near the bottom of the second screenshot.
What should I make of this incompatibility? Is this fatal to the argument in the textbook?
The only justification I can imagine is that in the WKB text, the $-i = exp(3π/2)$ appears for the variable of $J_v(α)$, whereas in the Bessel notes, the $-i = exp(-π/2)$ appears as a specification of the dummy variable $t$ from the contour integral. So maybe it's okay to say that in the complex $t$ plane vs the complex $α$ plane, we can make different choices for which $arg(-i)$ appears in an nth root?
I'd appreciate any thoughts on the correct way to handle this issue, or generally the issue of there being different choices for the nth root of -i across various proofs/results that we might end up simultaneously incorporating into the same problem/scenario.
pg 203: https://i.imgur.com/qRNl0qm.jpeg
pg 204: https://i.imgur.com/mJVMG0g.jpeg

Please do not post screenshots of textbooks as part of your question.  In addition, how is this resolved in other textbooks?

@ZeroTheHero sorry I didn't realize. Should I edit it into an imgur link instead? I can't find other textbooks that treat this issue with Bessel functions. Airy functions seem more common, which makes a direct comparison difficult to unpack. Additionally I have a general question of mixing root choices here, of which this example is just a specific instance.

The Bessel and Airy functions are related by fractional orders and it could be that Bessel functions are annoying for this kind of matching, or there could be phase convention issues.  I would edit the main equations, link to the rest, but more importantly “check-my-work” questions are off-topic so you should rephrase so as to turn your post into something conceptual rather than technical.

Maybe explain the benefits (if any) of using Bessel over Airy up to this root issue?  I kinda think Airy is more natural as Bessels are for plane waves but maybe there’s a case to be made for Bessels…

@ZeroTheHero, I haven't studied Airy functions so far or that approach to WKB so I can't speak to the comparison. I think my question is not really about the best way to tackle WKB, but a conceptual issue (albeit framed through this example) about mixing root branches. Ultimately it is ever consistent for a proof that uses one root to contain an implicit lemma that uses a difference root?
