Is it ever acceptable for both principal and non-principal roots of $-i$ to appear in the same derivation?
I have encountered a derivation which involves the following claims:
First, using the definition of the modified Bessel function
$$(-i)^{\nu}J_{\nu}(iz) = I_{\nu}(z),$$
they claim
$$(-i)^{1/3}iJ_{1/3}(iz) = -I_{1/3}(z),$$
which implies the choice of branch $-i = \exp(3i\pi/2).$ Shortly thereafter, they invoke the large argument $z \rightarrow \infty $ form of $J_{\nu}(z)$:
$$J_{\nu}(z) \rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{2}{{\pi}z}}\cos\left(z - \frac{v\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$
I studied the proof of the claim using pg. 10–12 of these notes. In that proof, we have at one point a factor of $(-i)^{-\nu-1}$, and there it is necessary to define $-i = \exp(-i\pi/2)$.
So I have a situation where the main derivation requires the non-principal root of $-i$ but relies implicitly on a lemma that requires the principal root. Is there any way that this can be regarded as mathematically consistent?
I will note that in the large argument Bessel proof, the factor of $(-i)^{-\nu-1}$ only arises in a specification of a complex dummy variable $t$ used in a contour integral that defines a representation of $J_{\nu}(z)$. Is it possibly okay that we can use different roots of $(-i)$ when in the $t$ complex plane variable versus the $z$ complex plane?

This question is about math, not physics, and belongs on [math.se].

@Ghoster there's a previous version of this question now deleted by the OP with more background: the initial question was on WKB and was also about using some roots.  This is a good occasion to remind everyone that one should edit questions rather than delete them and repost new ones.

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837559/2451

Hi pherytic. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

@Qmechanic at this point, how would you like me to handle this? I already deleted the original post because I was unaware of this editing policy here.

General tip: If a closed question is edited, it automatically enters the reviewer's queue.
